# Services are not assigned to any node after docker stack deploy

Tags: docker, deployment, devops, registry, docker-swarm

I'm using docker swarm for a tiny setup (two nodes only).

I'm deploying stacks on them through docker stack deploy commands.

Today, after an update, something went wrong, here is what I see when I do `docker stack ps project-name`:

```
ubuntu:~/project$ docker stack ps project-name

ID             NAME                     IMAGE                                                   NODE                         DESIRED STATE   CURRENT STATE          ERROR    PORTS
le5su9hvbvtd   project-name_backend.1   private.registry.com/spc/project/backend-prod:latest                                 Running         New 12 seconds ago
p8d85ktm36vp   project-name_frontend.1  private.registry.com/spc/project/frontend-prod:latest                                Running         New 11 seconds ago
jc3nxrrt078y   project-name_rabbitmq.1  rabbitmq:3-management                                   subdomain.example.com        Running         Running 8 seconds ago
i42otseddwtg   project-name_redis.1     redis:6-alpine                                          subdomain.example.com        Running         Running 8 seconds ago
```

So as you can see backend and frontend services have no NODE assigned to them.

When I type `docker service ls`:

```
g1wag3o0ftxm   project-name_backend             replicated   0/1        private.registry.com/spc/project/backend-prod:latest         
422sttk7rn3e   project-name_frontend            replicated   0/1        private.registry.com/spc/project/frontend-prod:latest
```

I also tried to update each service manually to increase the replicas to 1 with no avail.

I also suspected that it was due to building the images locally (without using a registry) so I pushed the images to a private registry and did `docker login` on both manager and worker nodes pointing at this registry.

Here is my docker compose config (I obfuscated some names so they might not fit with the ones on top.)

```
name: spc-app
services:
  backend:
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        traefik.constraint-label: traefik-public
        traefik.docker.network: traefik-public
        traefik.enable: "true"
        traefik.http.routers.spc-backend-http.rule: Host(`backend.spc.com`)
        traefik.http.routers.spc-backend-http.tls: "true"
        traefik.http.routers.spc-backend-http.tls.certresolver: le
        traefik.http.services.spc-backend-http.loadbalancer.server.port: "8000"
    image: private.registry.com/spc/project/backend-prod:latest

  frontend:
    build:
      context: /home/ubuntu/spc-app/frontend
      dockerfile: ./docker/prod/Dockerfile
      args:
        REACT_APP_BACKEND_HTTP: https://backend.spc.com
        REACT_APP_BACKEND_WS: wss://backend.spc.com/ws
    depends_on:
      backend:
        condition: service_started
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        traefik.constraint-label: traefik-public
        traefik.docker.network: traefik-public
        traefik.enable: "true"
        traefik.http.routers.spc-frontend-http.rule: Host(`www.spc.com`)
        traefik.http.routers.spc-frontend-http.tls: "true"
        traefik.http.routers.spc-frontend-http.tls.certresolver: le
        traefik.http.services.spc-frontend-http.loadbalancer.server.port: "80"
    image: private.registry.com/spc/project/frontend-prod:latest
    networks:
      default: null
      traefik-public: null

networks:
  default:
    name: spc-app_default
  postgres:
    name: postgres
    external: true
  traefik-public:
    name: traefik-public
    external: true
volumes:
  mediafiles:
    name: spc-app_mediafiles
  staticfiles:
    name: spc-app_staticfiles
```

I searched SO and the web for similar issues but Q/A were quite old and did not helped.

[EDIT]

I tried to update on of the broken services with `--force` flag but it freezes:

```
ubuntu:~/app$ docker service update --force --replicas=1 project-name_backend 
project-name_backend
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
1/1: new       [=====>                                             ]
```

Comment: Possible you are looking for `--with-registry-auth` if the images are on a secure private registry. Just logging on each node isn't going to help.

Comment: Also, sometimes the quickest way to figure out what problems Swarm is having running the container is to try run it yourself directly with `docker run`. If there are OCI errors or the image doesn't exist etc, `docker run` will report them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what was going wrong, I had already tried `--with-registry-auth` but that did not help to solve the problem.

I finally had to:

- restart my swarm by killing the manager node
- rejoin the workers
- set the labels correctly

And everything went back to normal.